# django-celery-results won't recieve results

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have celery setup and working together with django. I have some periodic tasks that run. The celery log shows that the tasks are executed and that they return something.

```
[2017-03-26 14:34:27,039: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: my_webapp.apps.events.tasks.clean_outdated[87994396-04f7-452b-a964-f6bdd07785e0]  
[2017-03-26 14:34:28,328: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Task my_webapp.apps.events.tasks.clean_outdated[87994396-04f7-452b-a964-f6bdd07785e0] succeeded in 0.05246314400005758s: 'Removed 56 event(s)

 | Removed 4 SGW(s)

'
```

But the result is not showing up on django-celery-results admin page.

These are my settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('BROKER_URL')
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_DB_SHORT_LIVED_SESSIONS = True  # Fix for low traffic sites like this one
```

I have also tried setting `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'`. I know the migrations are made (when using those settings), the table exists in the database:

```
my_webapp=> \dt
                           List of relations
 Schema |                 Name                 | Type  |     Owner      
--------+--------------------------------------+-------+----------------
 ...
 public | django_celery_beat_crontabschedule   | table | my_webapp
 public | django_celery_beat_intervalschedule  | table | my_webapp
 public | django_celery_beat_periodictask      | table | my_webapp
 public | django_celery_beat_periodictasks     | table | my_webapp
 public | django_celery_results_taskresult     | table | my_webapp
 ...
(26 rows)
```

Google won't give me much help, most answers is about old libraries like djcelery. Any idea how the get the results in the table?